# Can I create multiple dynamic carts with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

First, sorry for my bad english.

I can create `DBCont` number charts in different div dynamicly. Like this:

```
 $(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        for (var g = 0; g <= DbCount; g++)
        {
            var $container = $('<div id="div' + g + '" style="width: 400px; height: 200px;"></div>').appendTo(document.body);
            new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: $container[0],
                    type: 'areaspline',
                    marginRight: 10,
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    spacingRight: 20,
                    events: {
                        load: function() {
                            var series = this.series[0];
                            var series2 = this.series[1];
                            setInterval(function() {
                                var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                                        y1 = UsageGrafik[g],
                                        y2 = UsageGrafik2[g];
                                if (y1 > 120 || y2 > 120 || isNaN(y1) || isNaN(y2)) {
                                    y1 = 1;
                                    y2 = 1;
                                }
                                series.addPoint([x, y1], false, true);
                                series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
                            }, 5000);
                            ....
```

You can see this is a dynamic chart.
My problem is `setInterval(function())` sections are same for all charts. So all charts have  same graphics. Because `UsageGrafik[]` array is change every 5 seconds in same page with ajax.
Basicly, i want create multiple charts with different `setInterval(function())` section. Or another solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by closures. You have two options:

- wrap creating chart into function: `(function(g) { new Highcharts.Chart(...) })(g)`
- move out setInterval from definition:

  ```
      new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
              myIndex: g
              renderTo: $container[0],
              events: {
                  load: updateChart
              }
          },
          ...
      });

      function updateChart(e) {
                      var series = this.series[0];
                      var series2 = this.series[1];
                      var g = this.userOptions.chart.myIndex;
                      setInterval(function() {
                          var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                                  y1 = UsageGrafik[g],
                                  y2 = UsageGrafik2[g];
                          if (y1 > 120 || y2 > 120 || isNaN(y1) || isNaN(y2)) {
                              y1 = 1;
                              y2 = 1;
                          }
                          series.addPoint([x, y1], false, true);
                          series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
                      }, 5000);
                      ....
       }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just add my code `myIndex: g` and `var g = this.userOptions.chart.myIndex;` line. And work fine. Thank you again.